# Implementing custom comparison with CustomComparison and CustomEquality in F# tuple

Tags: f#, equals, icomparable, compareto, minimax

I'm here to ask a specific topic - I really found few info about this on the web.
I'm implementing a F# version of Minimax algorithm. The problem I'm having now is that I want to compare Leaf of my tree (data structure below). Searching the erros the VS gave to me I arrived to something like this:

The tree type I used to have:

```
type TreeOfPosition =
    | LeafP   of Position
    | BranchP of Position * TreeOfPosition list
```

and the temptative for implementing the IComparable

```
type staticValue = int
[<CustomEquality;CustomComparison>]
type TreeOfPosition =
    | LeafP   of Position * staticValue
    | BranchP of Position * TreeOfPosition list

    override x.Equals(yobj) = 
        match yobj with
        | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> (x = y)
        | _ -> false

    override x.GetHashCode() = hash (x)
    interface System.IComparable with
        member x.CompareTo yobj =
            match yobj with
            | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> compare (x) (y)
            | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare value of different types"
```

In the end, I just wanna get the max (and the min) of a list of LeafP by its static value (calculate in other function).

The code above compiles. However testing with this:

```
let p = new Position()
p.Add(1,BLACK)
let a = LeafP(p,1)
let b = LeafP(p,2)

let biger = compare a b
printf "%d" biger
```

I got a System.StackOverflowException in the "| :? TreeOfPosition as y -> compare (x) (y)" line in the override of the GetHashCode.

I have a thread in the hubfs.net (http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/15891.aspx) with I'm discussing my Minimax. Here you can find my lastest code (http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~pmdusso/works/Functional_Implementation_Minimax_FSharp.htm)

Thanks in advance,

Pedro Dusso

Well, I understood very clearly the idea but I can’t make it work. Remembering that I want to get the leaf with the max static value from a list of leafs (“List.max” :P), I think implementing the `CompareTo` or `Equals` will let the List.max works on them, correct?
I compose the things like this:

```
let mycompare x y = 
  match x, y with
  // Compare values stored as part of your type
  | LeafP(_, n1), LeafP(_, n2) -> compare n1 n2
  //| BranchP(_, l1), BranchP(_, l2) -> compare l1 l2 //I do not need Branch lists comparison
  | _ -> 0 // or 1 depending on which is list...

[< CustomEquality;CustomComparison >]
type TreeOfPosition =
    | LeafP   of Position * int
    | BranchP of Position * TreeOfPosition list

    override x.Equals(yobj) = 
       match yobj with
       | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> (x = y)
       | _ -> false

    override x.GetHashCode() = hash (x)
    interface System.IComparable with
       member x.CompareTo yobj = 
          match yobj with 
          | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> mycompare x y
          | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare value of different types"
```

The problems I’m having arranging the functions this way is:

1) The pattern discriminator 'LeafP' is not defined (with LeafP red-underlined)

2) (77,39): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'mycompare' is not defined, when I try a ALT  ENTER this message appear in my F# Interactive. The position {77,39} corresponds to the beginning of mycompare call (in GetHashCode).

What I’m doing wrong? What can I do better?

Thanks very much,

Pedro Dusso

**EDIT 3 - Solved**

Yes! I manage your answer to work finaly!

The final code is here:

```
[<CustomEquality;CustomComparison>]
type TreeOfPosition =
    | LeafP   of Position * int
    | BranchP of Position * TreeOfPosition list

    //Func: compare
    //Retu: -1: first parameter is less than the second
    //       0: first parameter is equal to the second
    //       1: first parameter is greater than the second
    static member mycompare (x, y) = 
        match x, y with
        // Compare values stored as part of your type
        | LeafP(_, n1), LeafP(_, n2) -> compare n1 n2
        | _ -> 0 // or 1 depending on which is list...

    override x.Equals(yobj) = 
        match yobj with
        | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> (x = y)
        | _ -> false

    override x.GetHashCode() = hash (x)
    interface System.IComparable with
       member x.CompareTo yobj = 
          match yobj with 
          | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> TreeOfPosition.mycompare(x, y)
          | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare value of different types"
```

Thanks for the feedback!

Pedro Dusso

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you're getting the exception because the `compare` function calls the `CompareTo` method of the values you're comparing (that is `x.ComaperTo(y)`). The values you're comparing using `compare` in the custom implementation of `CompareTo` are the values that the you are asked to compare (by the runtime), so this causes the stack overflow.

The usual way to implement `CompareTo` or `Equals` is to compare only some values that you store in your type. For example, you could write something like this:

**EDIT**: You can write a helper function `mycopare` to do the comparison (or you could simply change the `CompareTo` implementation). However, if you want to use a function, you need to move it inside the type declaration (so that it knows about the type - note that in F#, the order of declaration matters!)

One way of writing it is this:

```
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison >] 
type TreeOfPosition = 
  | LeafP   of Position * int 
  | BranchP of Position * TreeOfPosition list 

  override x.Equals(yobj) =  
     match yobj with 
     | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> 
        // TODO: Check whether both y and x are leafs/branches
        // and compare their content (not them directly)
     | _ -> false 
  override x.GetHashCode() = // TODO: hash values stored in leaf/branch

  interface System.IComparable with 
     member x.CompareTo yobj =  

       // Declare helper function inside the 'CompareTo' member
       let mycompare x y = 
         match x, y with
         // Compare values stored as part of your type
         | LeafP(_, n1), LeafP(_, n2) -> compare n1 n2
         | BranchP(_, l1), BranchP(_, l2) -> compare l1 l2
         | _ -> -1 // or 1 depending on which is list...

       // Actual implementation of the member
       match yobj with 
       | :? TreeOfPosition as y -> mycompare x y
       | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare value of different types"
```

This would work, because every call to `compare` takes only some part of the data, so you're making some progress.

Comment: Hey, I edited my own post.. I dont know if this is the right way to give you a feedback... If its not, I can change right away! Thanks, Pedro Dusso

Comment: @Pmdusso: Yes, I think this is good way of extending the question. I updated my answer to give a more complete example - you're right that just delcaring a function in advance (before the type declaration) wouldn't work.